# A question about updating prior

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have four random quantities $x, y, \alpha, \beta$ related with the following equation:$$x = \frac{\alpha y}{\alpha y + \beta (1-y)}~.$$
These follow some distribution (in my case its Beta distribution), but for simplicity let's assume $x \sim {\rm Unif}(0.3, 0.7)$, $y \sim {\rm Unif}(0, 0.2)$, $\alpha \sim {\rm Unif}(0.8, 1.0)$, $\beta \sim {\rm Unif}(0, 0.4)$. Suppose I am highly confident about the range of $x$, thus based on this confidence and the above equation, I would like to update the prior on other three variables. What would be some reasonable way to go about it?

Comment: It turns out this is addressed in this paper: https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/pdf/10.1080/01621459.2000.10474324?casa_token=2gIKFIRcK7QAAAAA:8FxxfWLMBFHNs4iircx2_I857u7do8nuOlGb61IgFzXFFe5cv5VDFTzxmJj_FoBkxW7EpDttnFXRQw , but I need a code to implement this.

Comment: X is a deterministic function of the others. Are you sure about those marginal. Further, do you have some independence assumptions?